# Laravel Cashier Subscriptions for Featured Posts

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I am currently using Laravel Cashier for my users so they can subscribe for premium accounts.

I also want to let any user make Featured Posts that are different from regular posts.

I want to charge the user $10/week for a featured post. I assume a Laravel Cashier subscription would work for this.

But I do not know how to link the Post, the User, and the Subscription together with Laravel Cashier.

Ideally there would be a `post_id` field in the subscriptions table. But there is not.

I need a way to check if a post is a featured post and if the user who owns the post has paid for it (the subscription is active)

With Laravel Cashier I can check if a user is subscribed for a premium account, but I don't know how to check if a post is subscribed to be featured by the post owner.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: You can simply add a column in database to save information if post is subscribed to be featured or not.

Comment: How can this be done with Laravel Cashier since it creates it's own subscription table?

Comment: I think you should  add a column in posts table right ? anyways you can add column in subscriptions table by creating a migration as we usually do `php artisan make:migration add_column_in_subscriptions  --table=subscriptions`